# How can access to data with multiindex in column python

Tags: python, pandas, yahoo

I have a dataframe with data from yahoo finance. This dataframe has two index column.

```
data = pdr.get_data_yahoo(['AAPL','AMAZ'],start = datetime.date(2018, 1, 1) ,end= datetime.date.today()) 

data
```

How can I do to get a subdataframe only with the information of AAPL since the DATA dataframe?

This is what I get:

```
Open    High    Low Close   Adj Close   Volume
AAPL    AMAZ    AAPL    AMAZ    AAPL    AMAZ    AAPL    AMAZ    AAPL    AMAZ    AAPL    AMAZ
Date                                                
2018-01-02  170.160004  0.55200 172.300003  0.56143 169.259995  0.53000 172.259995  0.54000 169.712067  0.54000 25555900    26229
2018-01-03  172.529999  0.53800 174.550003  0.58000 171.960007  0.50000 172.229996  0.55000 169.682510  0.55000 29517900    51364
2018-01-04  172.539993  0.55000 173.470001  0.63000 172.080002  0.51000 173.029999  0.60000 170.470703  0.60000 22434600    45018
2018-01-05  173.440002  0.60000 175.369995  0.75000 173.050003  0.60000 175.000000  0.65000 172.411560  0.65000 23660000    88304
2018-01-08  174.350006  0.65000 175.610001  0.70000 173.929993  0.60000 174.350006  0.65000 171.771179  0.65000 20567800    27933
2018-01-09  174.550003  0.69000 175.059998  0.69000 173.410004  0.64000 174.330002  0.65000 171.751465  0.65000 21584000    17100
2018-01-10  173.160004  0.62000 174.300003  0.63000 173.000000  0.60000 174.289993  0.60000 171.712051  0.60000 23959900    18038
2018-01-11  174.589996  0.60000 175.490005  0.69000 174.490005  0.55000 175.279999  0.63045 172.687408  0.63045 18667700    28100
2018-01-12  176.179993  0.55500 177.360001  0.62690 175.649994  0.55500 177.089996  0.60010 174.470642  0.60010 25226000    29550
```

This is what I want:

```
Open    High    Low Close   Adj Close   Volume
Date                        
2018-01-02  170.160004  172.300003  169.259995  172.259995  169.712067  25555900
2018-01-03  172.529999  174.550003  171.960007  172.229996  169.682510  29517900
2018-01-04  172.539993  173.470001  172.080002  173.029999  170.470703  22434600
2018-01-05  173.440002  175.369995  173.050003  175.000000  172.411560  23660000
2018-01-08  174.350006  175.610001  173.929993  174.350006  171.771179  20567800
2018-01-09  174.550003  175.059998  173.410004  174.330002  171.751465  21584000
2018-01-10  173.160004  174.300003  173.000000  174.289993  171.712051  23959900
2018-01-11  174.589996  175.490005  174.490005  175.279999  172.687408  18667700
```

Thanks

Comment: Your question is not clear. You want to print just first column AAPL?

Comment: Can you include your output dataframe in your question?

Comment: Yes! I just Edit the question. Sorry.

Comment: The idea is not change the way to generate the dataframe Data. I´m asking how to get all the information of AAPL.

Comment: Yahoo Finance has been deprecated, why are you using it?

Comment: I didn't get any message of deprecated. Anyway, can you give me another solution to download stock info? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution!

```
data.xs('AAPL',axis=1, level=1)

Open    High    Low Close   Adj Close   Volume
Date                        
2018-11-30  180.289993  180.330002  177.029999  178.580002  178.580002  39531500
2018-12-03  184.460007  184.940002  181.210007  184.820007  184.820007  40802500
2018-12-04  180.949997  182.389999  176.270004  176.690002  176.690002  41344300
2018-12-06  171.759995  174.779999  170.419998  174.720001  174.720001  43098400
2018-12-07  173.490005  174.490005  168.300003  168.490005  168.490005  42281600
2018-12-10  165.000000  170.089996  163.330002  169.600006  169.600006  62026000
2018-12-11  171.660004  171.789993  167.000000  168.630005  168.630005  47281700
2018-12-12  170.399994  171.919998  169.020004  169.100006  169.100006  35627700
2018-12-13  170.490005  172.570007  169.550003  170.949997  170.949997  31898600
2018-12-14  169.000000  169.080002  165.279999  165.479996  165.479996  40703700
2018-12-17  165.449997  168.350006  162.729996  163.940002  163.940002  44287900
2018-12-18  165.380005  167.529999  164.389999  166.070007  166.070007  33795000
2018-12-19  166.000000  167.440994  159.139999  160.889999  160.889999  48918227
```